# Validation checker city in form

Tags: validation, city

I'm working on one project and I need city checker in form.I have one form where user type country and city and I make drop down for country but for city it has to be long drop down so I decide to make "city validation checker".So when user type city form automatic check is city correct or incorrect.

Comment: My question is "how to make city validation in javascript or any other language (php,jquery)".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use some kind of searchable selectbox instead. There are tons of examples out there:
http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

http://jsearchdropdown.sourceforge.net/